# How to force left alignment in an aligned array of formulas?

Tags: equations, align

So I try

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\left.\begin{aligned}
\Phi (z)=-\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2\pi}{i}} \int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{N-iT}{x-z} dx ,\\  {\rm \Psi }(z)=-\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2\pi }{i}} \int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{N+iT}{x-z} dx-{\rm \Phi }(z)-z{\rm \Phi }^{'} (z),
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
```

But it renderes like

[image: this].

How to force it to be alligned left?

Comment: Not sure why you have the `\left.`, `\right.`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the alignment `&` character:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\left.\begin{aligned}
\Phi (z) &=-\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2\pi}{i}} \int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{N-iT}{x-z} dx ,\\  {\rm \Psi }(z)&=-\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2\pi }{i}} \int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{N+iT}{x-z} dx-{\rm \Phi }(z)-z{\rm \Phi }^{'} (z),
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```